# How to write a "comment" containing a period (.) in Brainfuck?

Tags: comments, brainfuck

Is there any way to do comments in Brainfuck that contain periods ('.')?

I know I can use basically every char that is not one of the commands, and it is ignored, but I would like to put a version number in a comment at the top of the file, and that contains a period.

Comment: Hmm, now if the comment(s) were themselves [part of] the code and the entire thing read as a modern, and very long, adaptation of Shakespeare ..

Comment: Not quite into Shakespeare, but an "interesting" commentary of the algorithm could indeed be fun. Hm, I'll keep that in mind.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a trick you can use: a loop will not execute what's inside if it's not run and fits syntactically.

```
[This is a comment.]+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.
```

Indeed, if you leave out the `[]`, this will print a NUL byte too much. You still cannot use brackets though ;)

This is akin to the shell construct:

```
if false; then
    this is a comment
fi
```